# How to search an inverted index implemented in SQL for multiple words?

Tags: sql, inverted-index

I'm attempting to make a search engine for an SQL database of commnets. I read online that one of the best ways of doing this would be to make a inverted index.

My tables for my inverted index are as below. Please let me know if this is incorrect and needs to be changed, that can be done easily.

[image]

You can find a single word fairly easily using this setup, as so:

```
SELECT comment_terms.term, comment_terms.frequency, comments.body FROM     comment_terms
INNER JOIN comments ON comment_terms.comment_name = comments.name
WHERE comment_terms.term = 'reddit'
ORDER BY frequency DESC
```

Which gives you this table:

```
term   | frequency | body
-------+-----------+-------
reddit |        24 | etc..
```

But I'm wondering how to search for multiple terms, so that the body of the returned result has to contain all the words you searched for. Please let me know if I need to regigg my tables to make this happen. Cheers.

### Expected Output

I'm expecting something along the lines of this:

```
GET COMMENTS THAT HAVE 'pig', 'dog'


| comment      |
|--------------|
| that pig dog |
| ...pig...dog |
```

Comment: Tag dbms used, since this is not covered by the ANSI/ISO SQL standard.

Comment: You are looking for `sql full text search`

Comment: jarlh - What part of the SQL I listed is not part of the standard?

Comment: Could you post a sample of the expected output as well?

Comment: Yup, done that now. cheers.

Comment: For multiple terms, I'd go with something like a union functionality *IF* I had no choice to do it elsewhere. So I'm going to be a little bit annoying here, and ask why you try to invent a search function in SQL, when many exists that will perform much better outside SQL, such as Lucene for example? What you're trying to do will start to perform worse and worse the more data and more complex your searches become. Just a thought that your time might be better spend on a different approach altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General approach:

**Zero!** your `comment_terms` table should have these fields (`Id`,`CommentId`, `TermId`)

**First** you have get all words of search query. 
For example you have `dog` with `id` of 1 and `pig` with `id` of 2.

**Second** you search in `comment_terms` for comments where have both Id (1 and 2) and have also 2 records in `comment_terms` table(`GROUP BY HAVING COUNT(commentId)`)